# How can I run apache2 server with the same domain as my frontend?

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I've seen that servers in different sites run as a part of main domain but I can not do it.
Example:
site: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
server [www.example.com/server](http://www.example.com/server)

In configuration file for apache server in server name field I wrote [www.example.com/server](http://www.example.com/server) and it's doesn't work.
How can I do it?

Comment: Is the goal to have www.example.com run from Server A and www.example.com/server run from Server B? 

Comment: yes, something like that

Comment: If this is the goal, you’ll want to look into using a proxy on Server A for anyone going to `/server`. It will be important to understand that all traffic to Server B will pass through Server A beforehand, so that first system will need the resources to effectively handle traffic for both A and B. If you would like to simplify this, you may want to consider using a subdomain, such as server.example.com, which can be set up to run in isolation of Server A.